# Mysql display query data and count

Tags: mysql

Just an amateur here needing a little help.
I have a table named tbl_inspection_areas.area_description
columns 'area_description' and 'display_tab'.

I want a query that returns 'area_description','display_tab' and the number of times each display tab occurs.

Like in the drawing below.

```
|   tbl_inspection_areas.area_description   |  tbl_inspection_areas.display_tab  |  count   |
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
|        engine                             |                38                  |    2     |
|        transmission                       |                38                  |          |
|        interior                           |                39                  |    1     |
|        wheels                             |                40                  |    3     |
|        glass                              |                40                  |          |
|        lights                             |                40                  |          |
```

This is the best I have come up with, but it only displays 3 rows and the count is in 3 seperate columns.
Any help would be great.

```
SELECT
      tbl_inspection_areas.area_description,
      tbl_inspection_areas.display_tab,
      SUM(CASE WHEN tbl_inspection_areas.display_tab = '38' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN tbl_inspection_areas.display_tab = '39' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count2,
      SUM(CASE WHEN tbl_inspection_areas.display_tab = '40' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count3,
      SUM(CASE WHEN tbl_inspection_areas.display_tab = '46' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count4
      FROM tbl_inspection_areas
      GROUP BY tbl_inspection_areas.display_tab
```

Comment: You are grouping by 1 column so I would expect only 3 rows in the result.

Comment: I think you want `GROUP BY tbl_inspection_areas.area_description, tbl_inspection_areas.display_tab` Although the question is not completely clear

Comment: I need to know how many area_description there are for each display tab and I need to know what they are. I could do it using 2 queries but I though it would be better as just 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      tbl_inspection_areas.area_description,
      tbl_inspection_areas.display_tab,
      COUNT(tbl_inspection_areas.display_tab)
      FROM tbl_inspection_areas
      GROUP BY tbl_inspection_areas.area_description,
               tbl_inspection_areas.display_tab,
```

Comment: ? Trailing comma :)

Comment: Adding an explanation of how the query answers the question would be helpful.